# Cannot delete site column in Edge only

Tags: sharepoint-server, browser-compatibility, browsers, office-2016

I have an oddly browser specific problem. I'm trying to delete some unwanted site columns from a content type. the content type is not yet in use anywhere. when I open to columns in the content type I see the delete button right where it should be but clicking on it does nothing. opening the site in firefox or IE the button performs normally.

It's as if JavaScript was disabled in Edge but google tells me that feature has been removed from the browser.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, I have tried using Edge.

- Created CT.
- Added a column to CT
- Removed column from CT.

All worked fine.

But the Remove button has a JavaScript `onclick`event:

```
javascript:if(!ConfirmDelete()) return false;_....)
```

I think, your Edge blocks a popup (confirm) window and this is why it seems that nothing is happening when you click "Remove" button.
[image]

**Update:**
In order to avoid popups to be blocked try these two things:

- Add your SharePoint site to the local intranet zone
- Turn off Block pop-ups feature in Edge (see screenshot below). Settings-->Advanced Settings --> Block pop-ups --> Off

[image]

Comment: That's quite possible. any ideas on a workaround?

Comment: @JonS. Update the answer with two workarounds.